# How to more easily and correctly add an additional condition to index to make code simpler and covered?

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

**Context**: 
Am trying to get from my dataset the records that meet the following conditions:

- If timestamp is between 01:00-05:00 a.m.
- And if the 'threat' value is '3'

**EDIT**:
So apparently I can print all the hours in the user-selected which is obtained per 'listCoords', by doing 'listCoord.index.hour'. Because hour is an attribute of DateTime in pandas. This one I use in the conditional-statement of my code: `color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6), 'red', '#5DBCD2')]`

To this code, I want to actually also add the condition: listCoord.index.Thread == '3' so that my code becomes:

`color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6) & (listCoord.index.Thread == '3'), 'red', 'blue')]`

But obviously 'Thread' is just a column name in my dataset and not an attribute of DateTime in pandas. **Question**: how can I add the second condition to the same line? So that my code becomes simpler and more covered.

**My dataset**:
new sample dataset points.csv:

```
Date/Time               Lat,                 Lon,                  Threat
2019-03-23 04:00:00,   -14.809489988279145,  26.191607774273443,    1
2019-03-23 04:00:00,   -14.792921094981814,  26.191716715339687,    2
2019-03-23 04:05:00,   -14.798684405083584,  26.162881454312586,    3
2019-03-23 04:10:00,   -14.80112670820822,   26.173830400821103,    2
```

**EDITED - My code**:

```
   def update_graph(datePicked, selectedData, selectedLocation):
    zoom = 10.5
    latInitial = -14.873619
    lonInitial = 26.106700
    bearing = 0

    if selectedLocation:
        zoom = 13.0
        latInitial = list_of_fixed_sensors[selectedLocation]["lat"]
        lonInitial = list_of_fixed_sensors[selectedLocation]["lon"]

    date_picked = dt.strptime(datePicked, "%Y-%m-%d")
    monthPicked = date_picked.month - 4
    dayPicked = date_picked.day - 1
    listCoords = getLatLonColor(selectedData, monthPicked, dayPicked)

    # print(listCoords.index.Threat)

return go.Figure(
        data=[
            # Data for all observations based on date and time
            Scattermapbox(
                lat=listCoords["Lat"],
                lon=listCoords["Lon"],
                mode="markers",
                hoverinfo="text + lat + lon",
                text=listCoords.index.hour,
                marker=dict(
                    showscale=True,
                    # the color is decided by the time of detection.
                    # color=np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23),
                    color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6), 'red', 'blue')]
```

Comment: To simply your threat filter you can do r=df1[df1['threat']==3] will create  a new dataframe called r with values from df1 equal to 3. Then you can do time_red=r.between_time() etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one liner would be

`df[(df['threat'] == 3) & df['Date/Time'].between_time('01:00', '05:00')]`

assuming `df['Date/Time'].dtype` is `datetime` if not use `pd.to_datetime`

For you edit case use:

`color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6) & (listCoord['Thread'] == '3'), 'red', 'blue')]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have actually during the past hour changed a lot in my code and now instead of making new lists, I take user input into a new list 'listCoords' and based on this new list I apply the the conditions. Could you please look at my post edit and see if you can provide pointers on the edited Question?

Comment: can you update the dataframe to include what you added. I think you want `color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6) & (listCoord['Thread'] == '3'), 'red', 'blue')]`

Comment: It Worked dude! (you have some spelling mistakes: 'color=np.where((listCoords.index.hour == 6) & (listCoord['Thread'] == '3'), 'red', 'blue')]' update your answer so I can pick at as the right answer :)